# pywin32 accept meeting invite

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32

I want to automatically accept meeting invites from certain people that I will direct to their specific folder in outlook.

I can't find any doc to tell me how to accept a meeting request.  Would it be like the *todo* line below or could I go about this a different way?

```
import win32com.client


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
auto_accept_meeting = root_folder.Folders['AutoAcceptMeetings']
print(auto_accept_meeting)

messages = auto_accept_meeting.Items
total_messages = len(messages)
print("Total messages {}".format(total_messages))

i = total_messages-1
while (i > 0) :
    message = messages[i]
    date = message.SentOn
    body = message.body
    #TODO message.acceptInvite
    i-=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [exchangelib](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/#description) to handle meeting invites.

From the documentation:

> It is also possible to process MeetingRequest messages that are received. You can reply to these messages using the AcceptItem, TentativelyAcceptItem and DeclineItem classes.